# how can get which uibutton when know indexPath.row of uitableview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a uitableview, it has 2 uibutton (button1 and button2) in each row. Now i know indexPath.row (ex:indexPath.row =2). how can get button1 when i had IndexPath.row of uitableview ? Please give me any suggestion to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

I used this code:

```
-(void)UpdateBtn:(NSNotification *)notification {

    //Update your button image code here
    shotIDPass =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey :@"videoIDstring"];
    NSLog(@"%@",shotIDPass);
    for (int i =0; i < [shotIDArray count]; i++) {
        if([[shotIDArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:shotIDPass])
        {
             NSLog(@"IndexPath of row %@",i); // get indexPath.row at here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where you want to get button ?

Comment: Assign some tag & check the tag of the button to de cide which one was pressed?!!

Comment: @iPatel: i want get button in uitableview

Comment: @hpiOSCoder: can you example code? thanks

Comment: @ThoaHuynh you want action for button or button itself ?

Comment: if u want button u can get in didselectRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom cell class.
Then use the tableview delegate methods.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (nil == cell) {
        cell = [[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
return cell;
}
```

when done, you add the action on the buttons.

You can do this in xib or storyboard to link with IBOutlet or programmatically in MyCustomCell.m

Answer (score 0):

just simply make IBOutlet your buttons and in method you just assign perform selector like this

```
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 [cell.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUPInside];
   [cell.button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(button2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUPInside];


  return cell;
  }
```

and then you just implement your method for button tap like this

> -(IBAction)button1 :(UIButton *)btn

```
   { 
     //Your Implementation

     }
```

and same like for second button

Answer (score 0):

## you must have to set each every button tag

here i explain to how to set button tag and find index.row from which button are clicked

- first of all you need to create a custom cell class and in that you
  need to define two button ..
- than after you need to create one NSMutableArray and how many rows are you need to add in tableview that all cell are add in array

-(IBAction)clickEvent:(UIButton *)sender;
-(void)viewDidload{
NSMutableArray *arrayCellCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int tagCount=1;

for (int i =0; i < [shotIDArray count]; i++){


AddPropertyCell *cell = [[AddPropertyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifiour"];
    cell.button1.tag=tagCount;
     [cell.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(clickEvent:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    tagCount++;
    cell.button2.tag=tagCount;
    [cell.button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(clickEvent:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    tagCount++;
    [arrayCellCollection addObject:cell];
      }}

-(IBAction)clickEvent:(UIButton *)sender
{int getIndexRow =0;
int a = sender.tag %2;

if (a==0)

{

getIndexRow=((a/2)-1);

}

else

{

getIndexRow=(a/2);

}

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath

{

return [arrayCellCollection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


}